# Making one Upstart script see environment variables of another

Tags: upstart

I have a server that starts with Upstart:

*/etc/init/server.conf*

```
description     "Server"  
start on runlevel [2345]  
stop on runlevel [!2345]  

respawn
exec /opt/myserver/runmyserver.sh
```

To operate properly it needs another OS service, so it is started with upstart as well:

*/etc/init/screen.conf*

```
description     "Screen"  
start on runlevel [2345]  
stop on runlevel [016]  
respawn

export DISPLAY=:1
exec /usr/bin/Xvfb $DISPLAY
```

The problem is that my server, when it runs, doesn't see DISPLAY var unless i link between them by replacing start stanza of server.conf to

```
start on started screen
```

I know that Upstart is event based parallel init system, and ordering is not promised, but i don't care which one started first or even if they started together as long as they share the same environment (variables).

What complicates things here is the fact that server.conf is actually not owned by me, and i don't want to modify it, unless I have to.

Is there a way to make DISPLAY var visible to server started in server.conf without modifying it?

Thanks